# How to know if a wireless router is able to set local wireless file sharing

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, modem

I want to buy a wireless ADSL modem router which also has the ability to set a wireless network between computers in office. Generally How could I know if it supports that?

Is it possible to use any wireless modem router for this purpose? Or some of them just have wireless to share the internet not to connect commuters to each other? And if it's this way how to find out the modem router is of each kind? One last thing, Does Any wireless modem router with the ability of LAN file sharing could share files directly via WIFI too?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you can use any ADSL modem, which has a WIFI. Inter-client communication can be managed in modem settings.

I haven't seen one with integrated storage yet, but most manufacturers make models with USB port and have an ability to use external usb storage to share data over network.

Also look at DSL type your ISP is using.

Comment: The storage does not matter to me. I just want a computer connects other computers using the same wireless router and share files/contents on the air. Is it Ok in almost all wireless ADSL modems to do this?

Comment: Yes, that is possible.

Comment: Thank You, Is there a name for this function or something that is mentioned in modems' specification table?

Comment: AFAIK there is not a unique name for this and I doubt that it's mentioned in specifications. Commonly it's `AP Isolation`.